# How do I remove numbers on phonepad if I press backspace button

Tags: android

I am  trying to make a a phonepad in android and I need to know how I make my backspace button work when I press it, it remove my last number and so on.

```
b13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int len=text.length();
        text.setText(text.getText().toString());
        String res=text.substring(0,len-1);

    }
});
```

b13 is  button id for remove button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Try this:

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) {
    String newText = myTextView.getText().toString()
        .substring(0, myTextView.getText.toString.length()-1);
    myTextView.setText(newText); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), there is a constant called KEYCODE_BACK that should achieve this behavior